# Kubernetes Dashboard v1.8.3 deployment

Tags: kubernetes

I am just trying to deploy kubernetes Dashboard in a namespace called "test".

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v1.8.3/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml

I just replaced namespace from kube-system to test  from the above yaml file and executed as below.

```
kubectl apply -f kubernetes-dashboard.yaml -n test
```

But, it is still trying to do something with namespace kube-system and getting the below error.

**Image:**

> gcr.io/google_containers/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.8.3

**Error:-**

```
2018/05/31 16:56:55 Starting overwatch
2018/05/31 16:56:55 Using in-cluster config to connect to apiserver
2018/05/31 16:56:55 Using service account token for csrf signing
2018/05/31 16:56:55 No request provided. Skipping authorization
2018/05/31 16:56:55 Successful initial request to the apiserver, version: v1.10.2
2018/05/31 16:56:55 Generating JWE encryption key
2018/05/31 16:56:55 New synchronizer has been registered: kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder-kube-system. Starting
2018/05/31 16:56:55 Starting secret synchronizer for kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder in namespace kube-system
2018/05/31 16:56:55 Synchronizer kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder-kube-system exited with error: unexpected object: &Secret{ObjectMeta:k8s_io_apimachinery_pkg_apis_meta_v1.ObjectMeta{Name:,GenerateName:,Namespace:,SelfLink:,UID:,ResourceVersion:,Generation:0,CreationTimestamp:0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC,DeletionTimestamp:<nil>,DeletionGracePeriodSeconds:nil,Labels:map[string]string{},Annotations:map[string]string{},OwnerReferences:[],Finalizers:[],ClusterName:,Initializers:nil,},Data:map[string][]byte{},Type:,StringData:map[string]string{},}
2018/05/31 16:56:57 Restarting synchronizer: kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder-kube-system.
2018/05/31 16:56:57 Starting secret synchronizer for kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder in namespace kube-system
2018/05/31 16:56:57 Synchronizer kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder-kube-system exited with error: kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder-kube-system watch ended with timeout
2018/05/31 16:56:59 Storing encryption key in a secret
panic: secrets is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:test:dashboard" cannot create secrets in the namespace "kube-system"

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/auth/jwe.(*rsaKeyHolder).init(0xc420254e00)
    /home/travis/build/kubernetes/dashboard/.tmp/backend/src/github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/auth/jwe/keyholder.go:131 +0x2d3
github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/auth/jwe.NewRSAKeyHolder(0x1a7ee00, 0xc42037a5a0, 0xc42037a5a0, 0x127b962)
    /home/travis/build/kubernetes/dashboard/.tmp/backend/src/github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/auth/jwe/keyholder.go:170 +0x83
main.initAuthManager(0x1a7e300, 0xc4201e2240, 0xc42066dc68, 0x1)
    /home/travis/build/kubernetes/dashboard/.tmp/backend/src/github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/dashboard.go:183 +0x12f
main.main()
/home/travis/build/kubernetes/dashboard/.tmp/backend/src/github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/dashboard.go:101 +0x28c
```

I created Secret, Rolebinding, Serviceaccount, deployment, Service & Ingress in the namesapce "test". Removed namespace from the yaml file and supplied thru -n "test" while creating.

Answer (score 2):

That happened because you created the ServiceAccount on a different namespace, namely `test` but as it says, it needs to be deployed in `kube-system` in order to be able to function.

You can find a nice walkthrough and possibly some clarifications [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Installation#recommended-setup)

However, if you still want to deploy on a different namespace, you would have to add the following role and rolebinding to your cluster:

```
# ------------------- Dashboard Role & Role Binding ------------------- #

kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-minimal
  namespace: kube-system
rules:
  # Allow Dashboard to create 'kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder' secret.
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  verbs: ["create"]
  # Allow Dashboard to create 'kubernetes-dashboard-settings' config map.
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["configmaps"]
  verbs: ["create"]
  # Allow Dashboard to get, update and delete Dashboard exclusive secrets.
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  resourceNames: ["kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder"]
  verbs: ["get", "update", "delete"]
  # Allow Dashboard to get, update and delete Dashboard exclusive secrets.
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  resourceNames: ["kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder"]
  verbs: ["get", "update", "delete"]
  # Allow Dashboard to get and update 'kubernetes-dashboard-settings' config map.
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["configmaps"]
  resourceNames: ["kubernetes-dashboard-settings"]
  verbs: ["get", "update"]
  # Allow Dashboard to get metrics from heapster.
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["services"]
  resourceNames: ["heapster"]
  verbs: ["proxy"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["services/proxy"]
  resourceNames: ["heapster", "http:heapster:", "https:heapster:"]
  verbs: ["get"]

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-minimal
  namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-minimal
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: test

---
```

I am afraid there is no other way around, you have to allow the service account to create secrets in kube-system namespace.

Comment: Nope, I replaced the namespace to test for service account also.  apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: test